# NSBezierPath Stroke color is wrong

Tags: cocoa, colors, border, xamarin.mac, nsbezierpath

I want to draw a 1px wide border around my custom `NSView` in `DrawRect` with `NSBezierPath`:

```
BorderColor.Set();
var path = NSBezierPath.FromRect(theRect);
path.LineWidth = 1;
path.Stroke();
```

Now `BorderColor` is set to `NSColor.Gray`, which I can see while debugging has an RGBA color code: (127,127,127,255)
But the 1px wide border which appears on the screen gets this color: (194,194,194,255)
When I set the `path.LineWidth` to 3, than I can see the 3 lines, the middle with wrong color (194..), the 2 wings with color (135,135,135,255) - which is close enough to the wanted (127..) color to be ok.
When I use four piece of 1px wide rectangles for border instead, and `Fill` these 4 rects, I also get the (135..) color, which is ok again.

I can use this rectangle based solution, I'm only wondering:
Is there a way to achieve the correct color for a 1px wide border with `NSBezierPath.Stroke`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're setting the stroke color correctly (we don't see how `BorderColor` is set up) it might be the case that you're measuring the color value on screen, which - in particular for a thin line - might have been anti-aliased so you're not seeing the original color but the output of the anti-aliasing algorithm.

Set the width to something bigger like 10 and measure the color in the middle of the 'blob' to make sure you're not chasing anti-aliasing artefacts..

Comment: Thanks, anti-aliasing caused the problem. Disabling it for the path drawing did the trick:

`var context = NSGraphicsContext.CurrentContext;`

`context.SaveGraphicsState();`

`context.ShouldAntialias = false;`

`//...Drawing the path...`

`context.RestoreGraphicsState();`

Comment: That might not actually be what you want - make sure you align your drawing to pixel boundaries. Turning off anti-aliasing is usually not the actual solution and should be used only under extreme circumstances (can't imagine any, though).

Comment: Thanks again, you are right, shifting the coordinates of the line with 0.5px (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016618/how-to-get-a-1-pixel-line-with-nsbezierpath?rq=1)) also can solve the problem.

I've also seen now, that my 1px wide line was 2px wide in reality before the coordinate shifting (or the anti-alias disabling). I can see this when I draw it into the middle of a view. I've only seen it 1px wide earlier because I've drawn it at the View's Bounds, so the 2. line was clipped.

Comment: Great to hear it helped!