# How to make sharp border of shape in CGrect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I am using CGrect to draw circle with border but i didn't get sharp border of circle here is my code:

```
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(lastPoint1.x - CircleRadius ,lastPoint1.y - CircleRadius,CircleDia,CircleDia);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [Util_color getThemeColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0);
     CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, YES);
    CGContextSetLineCap(cox,kCGLineCapRound);
```

but i still get blur border ! Is there any way to get sharp border using CGrect?

Comment: At least use `CGRectIntegral` on the first line. This rounds the coordinates to integer pixels. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9975374/526547

Comment: it apply on view i want to apply in CGrect

Comment: Integral coordinates are exactly the wrong way round. See the illustrated article I posted in my answer for why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a 1 pixel line with NSBezierPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016618/how-to-get-a-1-pixel-line-with-nsbezierpath)

Answer (score 2):

You're drawing between pixels. See here for an explanation and a fix: http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/are-your-rectangles-blurry-pale-and-have-rounded-corners/

(This is a duplicate of [How to get a 1 pixel line with NSBezierPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016618/how-to-get-a-1-pixel-line-with-nsbezierpath/22267934) for which I wrote this explanation originally)

Comment: i don't want to use layer because i want circle in UIimage

Comment: What do you mean by "layer"? That blog post is not about layers, it is about Quartz drawing.

Comment: NSBezierPath use the layer when it add it to UIImageview not in original images and I want on UIimage  then whats the solution ?

Comment: This is the first time you mentioned that you're using layers. Can you put more information about what you're doing into your question? There is a big difference between whether you are drawing a bezier path or whether you're sticking it into a layer for that to draw it.

Comment: I have one UIimage in which i want to draw circle into image and i upload that image to server. But when i draw circle, its edge(border) is not sharp it looks blur with my above code ...

Comment: Post your code. There is no UIImage in the code you posted. We can't help if you leave out half the question.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that what the OP means by sharp border is one that hasn't had [anti-aliasing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455178-cgcontextsetshouldantialias?language=objc) applied.

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, NO);
```